# Is there an easy common gis abstraction available in .Net

Tags: .net, api, standards

Is there an easy common gis abstraction available in the .Net programming world that cuts the dependency to a concrete gis implementation, e.g. to the esri silverlight/wpf sdk.

... for example OpenLayers is such a library for several map providers in JavaScript. By using an IoC container (like Spring.Net) the dependency could be hidden. I noticed the GeoAPI buth this seems too complex for an easy abstraction level, I think.